# Using grid with frames is very slow

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create Conway's Game of Life in python3 using [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter). I am attempting to initialize all the tiles (like a chessboard for those who don't know of the game of life). The grid is displaying correctly, however, it is way too slow (it takes about 4 or 5 seconds). Here is my code:

```
for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        tile = Frame(root, width=30, height=30, bg="#000")
        tile.grid(row=i, column=j, padx=1, pady=1)
```

note: `h` and `w` values (dictate how many pixels the tiles are wide and tall) aren't very large at all. only like 20x30.

I have found a similar question here, but it sounds like the number of iterations is vastly different:

[tkinter is very slow - how to speed it up or use a different library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624833/tkinter-is-very-slow-how-to-speed-it-up-or-use-a-different-library)

***Is there something wrong with my implementation or should I resort to an alternate library?***

SIDE QUESTION: also with all my tiles named the same exact thing, I'm not sure how to select a single one in order to change its background color.

```
tile.config(background = "#FFFFFF")
```

Comment: Why do you need Frames? They are very expensive to create and maintain and absolutely unnecessary in your case. Just draw a bunch of vertical and horizontal lines on the canvas.

Comment: i was using frames so that i can set background colors for individual tiles, which occurs later on.

Comment: Then you should use rectangles on the canvas.

Comment: What platform are you running on? I'm guessing OSX.

Comment: no im using linux.

Comment: The simple answer to your side question is to use one of the collection types instead of overwriting the same variable and simply populate them.

Comment: @nae   rather than changing the colors of every square, i discovered the canvas.delete("all") function, then i just repopulate with the same module. i finished my Game of Life project, but ill google what collection types are. thank you Nae.

Comment: @ggkfox I mean like `list`, `dict`, `tuple` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DyZ hit the nail on the head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757411/grid-in-tkinter-very-slow#comment84516635_48757411). Frames were slow and Rectangles were much easier. I just thought I put it in a much easier to read location.